# What are difference between calling `connectGatt` on BluetoothDevice vs `connect` on BluetoothGatt

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

When there's already BluetoothGatt that is retrieved from `connectGatt`. Have not `close()`d the server, but is disconnected. At this point, what is the difference in calling `connectGatt` on BluetoothDevice with the same callback object vs calling `connect` on `bluetoothGatt` that was retrieved?

Comment: Did you ever find out about this?